# Solving system of equations with complex numbers

Tags: equation-solving

I have two equations and two unknowns. The coefficients are complex. How do I solve them using matrices? Or any other method? Here is an example:

Trying to find *X* and *Y*

```
(40 + 50i)(_X_) - 70(_Y_) = 130

-40(_X_) + (170 - 50i)_Y_ = 0
```

I can do two equations two unknowns on my TI-84 without complex numbers using matricies. It can't do these. I'm new to Mathematica, can anyone help?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 
1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 
2) Read the [faq]!
3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge.
Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)!

Comment: Go to the [docs](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/EquationSolving.html) and click on "Learning Resources"

Comment: Have a look at `Solve` and don't use those underscores.

Answer (score 3):

There are two ways to do this. One easy way is to use the Solve function:

```
Solve[(40 + 50 I) x - 70 y == 130 && -40 x + (170 - 50 I) y == 0, {x, y}]

{{x -> 6/5 - (11 I)/5, y -> 2/5 - (2 I)/5}}
```

Or, if you must use matrices, you can solve an equation like ax=b by using matrix inverse.  Solving for x, x=Inverse[a].b, where the dot is the matrix inner product:

```
a = {{40 + 50 I, -70}, {-40, 170 - 50 I}};
b = {{130}, {0}};

Inverse[a].b
{{6/5 - (11 I)/5}, {2/5 - (2 I)/5}}
```

Mathematica is particular about I and i, so be sure to use capital I or the special imaginary lower case i, which is created by <kbd>Esc</kbd>ii<kbd>Esc</kbd>.

Answer (score 2):

Your equations have several syntax errors.  `_X_` is not a legal variable, `I` must be used instead of `i`, and `==` used instead of `=`.  With these changes,

```
NSolve[{(40 + 50 I) x - 70 y == 130, -40 x + (170 - 50 I) y == 0}, {x, y}]
```

gives the desired answer.

```
{{x -> 1.2 - 2.2 I, y -> 0.4 - 0.4 I}}
```

As Jens commented, please review Mathematica documentation.

Answer (score 1):

One method is to write as xr+I*xi, where xr is the real part and xi is the imaginary part. Then

```
Reduce[{(40 + 50 I) (xr + I xi) - 70 (yr + I yi) == 130,
-40 (xr + I xi) + (170 - 50 I) (yr + I yi) == 0,
{xr, xi, yr, yi} \[Element] Reals}, {xr, xi}]
```

gives

```
yr == 2/5 && yi == -(2/5) && xr == 6/5 && xi == -(11/5)
```

and if you plug those back into your original you see this is a solution.